# How to update mac os

Tags: macos

I have Mac os 10.7.5 in my mac mini. I have tried to update but it shows your software is already up to date. I want to update from 10.7.5 to 10.8.x (latest).  Could you suggest me the steps? Problem is that Xcode 5 is not working on the installed OS.

Comment: See answers to your previous question.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mac is up-to-date with the version 10.7. 
If you want to move to 10.8 you'll have to buy it ( hence this update is not shown from the apple menu).

Go to the mac app store and search for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score -1):

You need to purchase [the upgrade](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/os-x-mountain-lion/id537386512) from the app store. Be sure to backup your machine just to be safe!